# Why isn't this RedCode MOV working?

Tags: assembly, corewars, redcode

So, I'm in assembly class, and to keep things interesting, we have tournaments bi-weekly with Core Wars. I'm trying to make a simple application that copies an IMP further down in memory, then jumps back and has two IMPs going at the same time. The idea is once I get this part working to put it into a tight loop and make more than two.

Here's my code:

```
JMP START        ; Jump to the starting point

ADDR DAT #1, #0  ; Remember the last address we dropped at
MOVE MOV 0, 1    ; The imp to be copied

START            ; Starting point
ADD #-1, ADDR    ; Take 1 off the address
ADD #80, ADDR    ; Move 80 forward
ADD #1, ADDR     ; Make that 81

MOV MOVE, ADDR   ; Move the imp to the ADDR
SPL ADDR         ; Split a new processes at the ADDR

JMP MOVE
```

However, what's happening is the first `MOV`/`SPL` doesn't work, and so only the first IMP is running. Where am I going wrong in this logic? It works if I remove `ADDR` and just use a magic number.

Here's a screen snippet of the memory before it starts running.

[image: Screen Snippet of Memory]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
MOV MOVE, ADDR   ; Move the imp to the ADDR
SPL ADDR         ; Split a new processes at the ADDR
```

to:

```
MOV MOVE, @ADDR   ; Move the imp to the ADDR
SPL @ADDR         ; Split a new processes at the ADDR
```

And change `JMP MOVE` to `JMP START` if you want the loop to work.

Plus you should change the first line to `ORG START` instead of `JMP START`

---

I think i misunderstood part of you question, it looks like you're only trying to create two imp processes whereas i said to make a loop, you have only 2 imps running if you make it something like this:

```
org start

addr dat #0, #1

start
    add #80, addr
    mov imp, @addr
    spl @addr

imp mov $0, $1
```

But it doesn't jump back to the start and overwrite the original instructions.